# SSRS button to go to subreport in excel export

Tags: reporting-services, export-to-excel

We are creating a Summary report with lot of Sub-Reports linked to it in SSRS. When Summary report is exported as excel all Sub-Reports should be exported as separate tabs. So far it is working.

Now the issue is we need to have button in each row on the Summary report (in the tablix) , which when clicked opens up the relevant tab in Excel.This behavior is expected after report has been exported to Excel.I have been looking to find to solutions to this but haven't fount anything so far.
Any pointer/suggestion would be a great help.

Thanks
VSh

Comment: Are you still having an issue?

Comment: It worked perfectly. We had actually scrapped the requirement. After getting a response from you , was able to implement it successfully. Thanks a ton for your help.

Comment: No worries, glad I could help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add bookmarks and bookmark links to a report when you want to provide a customized table of contents or to provide customized internal navigation links in the report. Typically, you add bookmarks to locations in the report to which you want to direct users, such as to each table or chart or to the unique group values displayed in a table or matrix. You can create your own strings to use as bookmarks, or, for groups, you can set the bookmark to the group expression.

Here is the Microsoft documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/add-a-bookmark-to-a-report-report-builder-and-ssrs

Comment: Thanks so much. It is working. Bookmark helped us navigate to and fro in the exported Excel.